# creating multiple containers and modifying their divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a popup, within the pop up is the following code, it contains a “container”, which forms a template:

```html
<form method="post" class="signin" action="#">
    <div id='container'>
        <div>
            <div id="divFeeTitle"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I am populating the div via a container / for loop:

```js
//go into JSON object and print out properties
for(var index=0; index<LineItem.length; index++){
    DisplayTitle(LineItem[index]);
}
```

Display Title method does this:

```js
function DisplayTitle(Object){
    $('#divFeeTitle').html(Object.Title);
}
```

The trouble is, if there are 1+ objects, the divFeeTitle gets overwritten by the last object in the list. When if there are 1+ objects I need it to be laid out in order.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, you could try to use `.append()` instead of `.html()`

So your DisplayTitle function would look like:

```
function DisplayTitle(Object){

  $('#divFeeTitle').append(Object.Title);

}
```

Comment: That work's but what I really need are multiple containers, one after the other for each title (and other properties within that object) , as I will eventually be listing different values in each despite the base template being the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop overwriting your data, be sure you save your data first:

```
var data = $('#divFeeTitle').html();
$('#divFeeTitle').html(data+Object.Title);
```

You can add an extra `<br>` if needed etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23475207/creating-an-array-of-containers-using-jquery This question should make clear what I am trying to do.