# Creating an array of containers using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Template:

```
<Div id='Container'>

<div id='name'></div>
<div id='address'></div>

</div>
```

I want to then use this template by using a for loop to replicate it with the name and address within each container being different.

I don't want to recreate the whole template dynamically, as the template will never change.

So the output on the body should be like this:

```
        <Div id='Container'>

        <div id='name'></div>
        <div id='address'></div>

        </div>

    <Div id='Container1'>

    <div id='name'></div>
    <div id='address'></div>

    </div>


<Div id='Container2'>

<div id='name'></div>
<div id='address'></div>

</div>
```

Output on body:

```
Container:

Tom
sample address

Container 1:

Richard.
address 2

Container 3:

John

address 3
```

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same ID in valid HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    var container = document.createElement('div'),
        name = document.createElement('div'),
        address = document.createElement('div');
    container.id = 'Container' + i;
    name.className = 'name';
    address.className = 'address';
    container.appendChild(name);
    container.appendChild(address);
    document.body.appendChild(container);
}

//same thing using jQuery + people array for easy population
var people = [
    {name: "Tom", address: "sample address"},
    {name: "Richard", address: "address 2"},
    {name: "John", address: "address 3"}
];

for(var i = 0, len = people.length; i < len; i++){
    var container = $("<div id='Container" + i + "'><div class='name'>" + people[i].name + "</div><div class='address'>" + people[i].address + "</div></div>");
    $('body').append(container);
}
```

Comment: So there is no way I can just hardcode the divs in the html (maybe making the ids an array value), take a copy of that and modify the properties directly? If that makes sense.

Comment: @bobo2000: There probably is, but that'd be relatively inefficient.

Comment: This solution would be a lot shorter / easier to read if it actually used jQuery.

Comment: @BrianGlaz: I just got out of work, typing jQuery on my phone is a pain. But feel free to edit my answer to include a jQuery option, if you wish.

Comment: please do Brian I would like to see how this would look in jquery, would help me to learn.

Comment: Modified to use jQuery and a people array.

Comment: thanks, if i were to append the containers into another div and not the body of the DOM what is the best way to do that? should i just change the name of body to the div name?

Comment: You can just modify `$('body')` with any valid selector. `$('#myDiv')` for an element with an id of my `myDiv` for example.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is pure javascript and of course works, but you asked how to do it in jQuery, so here's a jQuery version using the $.each() method to iterate over an array of objects:

```
 var mydata = [{"name": "Tom", "address": "123 Happy Land"},{"name": "Dick", "address": "456 Main Street"},{"name": "Harry", "address": "789 End of the World"}]
  $.each(mydata, function() {
    var template = '<div class="container">';
    template += '<div class="name">'+this.name+'</div>';
    template += '<div class="address">'+this.address+'</div>';
    template += '</div>';
    $('body').append(template);
  });
```

EDIT:
If you need your containers numbered with an unique id that's easy too:

```
var mydata = [{"name": "Tom", "address": "123 Happy Land"},{"name": "Dick", "address": "456 Main Street"},{"name": "Harry", "address": "789 End of the World"}]
  $.each(mydata, function(index) {
    index=index+1; //so you start at 1 not 0
    var template = '<div id="container'+index+'">';
    template += '<div class="name">'+this.name+'</div>';
    template += '<div class="address">'+this.address+'</div>';
    template += '</div>';
    $('body').append(template);
  });
```